# How to Change Paper Size of a print dialog programatically C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, crystal-reports-2008

I Want to Change the paper size to a user-defined paper size programatically in C#  for Eg: 10x12 is my Paper Size.
It is much better if you help me in how to print in Crystal Report with the paper size 10x12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN OnBegin Event of the print document class,set the below coding for custom paper size :

```
     Dim xCustomSize As New PaperSize("Custom", 10, 12)
            xCustomSize.PaperName = PaperKind.Custom

 PrintDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize =xCustomSize
```

*** For Crystal Report : ***

```
MYCRYSTALREPORT crpt = new MYCRYSTALREPORT();
crpt.PrintOptions.PaperSize = xCustomSize ;
```

for more detail: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e647fac-d5cd-42b7-a1e6-db6d6cf97c57/setting-pagesize-for-crystal-report?forum=vscrystalreports

Comment: THANKS. Can u help How to do it for a crystal report?